# selecting textareas

Tags: jquery, attributes, selection

I am trying to select specific element types in a row and change their attribute, specifically the id and name attributes.

Using the following works fine for single line text input boxes:

```
$('input:text', newRow).attr('id','os' + newRowNum ).attr('name','os' + newRowNum );
```

however, when I change the html to:

```
<td><textarea name="os2" cols="24" rows="3" id="os2"></textarea></td>
```

the script will no longer find the attributes and change them. A textarea is an input element ... no?

I have also tried:

```
$('input:text, textbox', newRow).attr('id','os' + newRowNum ).attr('name','os' + newRowNum );
```

and

```
$('input[type=text], textbox', newRow).attr('id','os' + newRowNum ).attr('name','os' + newRowNum );
```

but neither work.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the selector to:

```
$('textarea', newRow).attr('id','os' + newRowNum ).attr('name','os' + newRowNum );
```

Comment: Crap ... yes this works just fine. I swear I thought I had tried that. But, a textarea is a text input box yes? Just curious why that would not work?

Comment: a text box isn't an input box in the same way, essentially the select "input:text" is short hand for "input[type='text']" and since a textarea is not an input element it would never match

Answer (score 1):

`<textarea>` elements do not match the [`:text`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/text) selector.

This doesn't work because it's `<textarea>` not `<textbox>`.

```
$('input:text, textbox', newRow)
```

So this should work:

```
$(":text, textarea", newRow)...
```

Comment: Does not work. It seems that it has to be 'textarea' only, as Michael said in the precious response.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly.

```
  $('input:text')
```

will specifically look for `<input>` tags.

You may need to consider:

```
 $('textarea') ...
```

Comment: Yeah I got that from Michaels' post. Thanks